# Convert multiple character vectors to date with apply returns a number in R

Tags: r, date, apply

I have a df with 4 date columns as character vectors:

```
print(df)
       Date1      Date2      Date3      Date4
1 2016-12-05       <NA> 2016-11-24 2017-12-05
2 2007-10-15 2009-09-18 2007-10-15 2017-10-15
3 2005-07-22 2009-06-20 2005-07-22 2017-07-22
4 2008-01-03 2017-07-25 2008-01-03 2018-01-03
```

If I apply:

```
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) as.Date(x, origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

I get as a result:

```
print(df)
     Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4
[1,] 17140    NA 17129 17505
[2,] 13801 14505 13801 17454
[3,] 12986 14415 12986 17369
[4,] 13881 17372 13881 17534
```

I've solved the problem using `lapply` instead of `apply` but I would like to know what is happening inside `apply` for returning dates as a number.

Comment: Unclassed dates are being reflected in terms of number of days since 1970-01-01. Hope this helps @Rubén.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP *would like to know what is happening inside apply for returning dates as a number*.

The help page `?apply` says

> In all cases the result is coerced by `as.vector` to one of the basic vector types before the dimensions are set

The help page `?as.vector` says

> All attributes are removed from the result if it is of an atomic mode, but not in general for a list result.

As already mentioned by [Akarsh Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099138/convert-multiple-character-vectors-to-date-with-apply-returns-a-number-in-r#comment89185981_51099138), Date objects have a `class` attribute. Removing the `class` attribute will leave just the plain number of days since 1970-01-01.

Here is a code snippet for demonstration:

```
x <- as.Date("2016-12-05")
x
#> [1] "2016-12-05"
attributes(x)
#> $class
#> [1] "Date"
y <- as.vector(x)
y
#> [1] 17140
attributes(y)
#> NULL
```